# Tapestry 5 - POST to endpoint on component and get back JSON in one scenario or do redirects in other scenarios

Tags: ajax, tapestry

I am adding a new requirement to a legacy Tapestry login component to show a popup if a certain error condition happens on login, without doing a page reload.

Currently the login component uses standard Tapestry form submission - i.e. the login creds are POSTed up to the server on form submission, login processing is done, and based on the result Tapestry does an appropriate redirect by returning either a page Class, or a page object injected with `@InjectPage` which has had some setup done on it - standard Tapestry stuff really.

I need to leave the current logic as it is - i.e. keep Tapestry doing the redirects it does currently, but I also need the following extras:

1. The POST request must be done via AJAX
2. The result if I meet my new error condition must just be plain JSON, so the client knows to display the popup.
3. The login endpoint must be able to be called from other browser-based clients that know nothing about Tapestry and vice-versa Tapestry. But the Tapestry redirects should work (if this is even possible - how baked into the server and client-side framework are the redirects?) as well as the sending down of plain JSON.

I think (1) and (2) are pretty straightforward to achieve using Tapestry zones, but I am struggling to see how (3) fits in. Can Tapestry support providing an HTTP(S) api, callable via AJAX, that provides redirects as well as plain-old JSON responses on any type of web client? I suspect if this is possible there is a good pattern for doing it, but I just can't find any docs or examples anywhere, probably because most of the time people don't use non-tapestry rendered clients with Tapestry back ends.

If this does turn out to be do-able, I foresee a sea of bad hacks and pitfalls if I don't ask the community for advice and just wade in myself, so any pointers would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a webservice which accepts a username / password and returns a JSON success / error
2. Create an ajax based tapestry login page which calls the webservice in it's onValidate() event
3. Re-use the webservice for non-tapestry apps
4. If the webservice is part of the tapestry app, you might call the java LoginService directly in the tapestry app instead of going through the webservice wrapper.

Comment: Yes, re-architecting and refactoring the whole solution is what I'd ideally do, but let's assume I can't. I'm aware it will be inferior to a from-scratch solution, but my question is - is it possible to modify my legacy code without any heavyweight refactoring to achieve what I want, or would I just be fighting too hard against the constraints of the framework?

Comment: I often will create an "end point" as a Tapestry page; those have reasonably predictable URLs that can be accessed outside the application. From your activate event handler, you can return a JSONObject, or invoke Response.sendRedirect().

Comment: Component event URLs are less predictable and more likely to change when something minor in your page structure changes.

Comment: Is it really such a huge re-architecture? I'm guessing you already have a onValidate() in your login page. It's just a case of tweaking that and adding a zone parameter to your form innit? Perhaps not